# Integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\frac{x^4-1}{x\cos(\pi\ln x)+1}+2x^2+2}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, logarithms, closed-form, conjectures

I need your help with this integral:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\frac{x^4-1}{x\cos(\pi\ln x)+1}+2\,x^2+2}.$$

I wasn't able to evaluate it in a closed form, although an approximate numerical evaluation suggested its value could be $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Just an observation: $x \cos(\pi\ln x)=\Re\left(x^{1+\pi\sqrt{-1}}\right)$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let us introduce the notation
$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\frac{x^4-1}{x\cos(\pi\ln x)+1}+2x^2+2}.$$

1. Now observe that
   \begin{align}\frac{1}{\frac{x^4-1}{x\cos(\pi\ln x)+1}+2x^2+2}&=
   \frac{1}{x^2+1}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{x^2-1}{x\cos(\pi\ln x)+1}+2}=\\
   &=\frac{1}{x^2+1}\cdot\frac{\cos(\pi\ln x)+\frac1x}{x+\frac1x+2\cos(\pi\ln x)}.
   \end{align}
2. Using this formula and making the change of variables $x\leftrightarrow \frac1x$, we can rewrite $\mathcal{I}$ as
   $$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+1}\cdot\frac{\cos(\pi\ln x)+x}{x+\frac1x+2\cos(\pi\ln x)}dx.$$
3. Summing the last  representation with the initial one, we get
   $$2\mathcal{I}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \mathcal{I}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Whoa. You made that look incredibly simple. Can I ask how you knew to apply that technique? Is it the fact that $\log(1/x) = -\log(x)$? I've never really seen the "representing the integral two different ways and summing them" used so effectively on such a hard looking integral - great stuff, thanks.